# How do I stop default localhost virtualhost from directing to named virtual host?

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, localhost, virtualhost

So a little background info first:

- using PhpStorm IDE (actually not important but just relaying info)
- using Vagrant running an Ubuntu 14.04 box (use of Vagrant also not important)
- have main `/var/www/` folder on virtual server
- have named site `default.dev` in `/var/www/default.dev/` folder on virtual server
- contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin email@email.com
      ServerName localhost
      DocumentRoot /var/www/
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.dev.conf` file:

  ```
  <VirtualHost default.dev:80>
      ServerAdmin email@email.com
      ServerName default.dev
      ServerAlias default.dev
      DocumentRoot /var/www/default.dev/src/
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- both sites have been enabled via sudo a2ensite
- Windows **hosts** file contains the following:

  ```
  192.168.10.10  localhost
  192.168.10.10  default.dev (plus commented out Vagrant ID)
  ```
- trying to setup PHP Unit testing which is a bit weird with PhpStorm + Vagrant and requires me to be able to directly access localhost separately from my test site
- default.dev can be accessed correctly in browser
- going directly to localhost incorrectly loads up the contents of the default.dev site
- so for example:
  trying to access file located at `/var/www/phpinfo.php` via `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` throws a 404 error on the site whose files are located at `/var/www/default.dev/src/`

so again:

going to default.dev (located at `/var/www/default.dev/src/`) in browser works fine

HOW do I configure my system so that I can access `/var/www/` in browser via `localhost`?

BIG thanks to everyone in advance for taking the time to read this,
and an even **BIGGER** thanks to anyone taking the time/effort to respond

Comment: Just to check, you want the `localhost` on your Windows system to open the `localhost` website on the webserver? O.o

Comment: well in order to fully use phpunit within my IDE, my IDE needs to be able to access a file that it places at /var/www/filename.ext and then tries to access via http/localhost/filename.ext, but it can't get to that file, because the vitual machine is directing http/localhost/filename.ext to /var/www/default.dev/src/filename.ext which throws a 404 on the site that is hosted there

Comment: Is the apache site file actually called `default.dev.conf`?

Comment: no that's the name of the virtual host file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ the site is named default.dev

Comment: yes, the name of the virtualhost file is what I meant. Usually, if only an IP is asked for, Apache picks the first site, and that usually comes from whichever file got loaded first. If the default.dev file is actually called `default.dev.conf`, it should be loaded after `000-default.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apache documentation, `ServerName` requires an [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). `localhost` name is not a Fully qualified domain name.

Try to change your `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    ServerName default.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Change Windows hosts:

```
 192.168.10.10  default.localhost
```

According to apache manual:

```
Syntax: <VirtualHost addr[:port] [addr[:port]] ...> ... </VirtualHost>

Addr can be any of the following, optionally followed by a colon and a port number (or *):

 The IP address of the virtual host;
 A fully qualified domain name for the IP address of the virtual host (not recommended);
 The character *, which acts as a wildcard and matches any IP address.
 The string _default_, which is an alias for *
```

So, I suggest to change:

```
 <VirtualHost default.dev:80>
```

with:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
```